# Compute size of object if it has to be aligned as a specific type

Tags: c++, sizeof, memory-alignment

Is there a "sizeof if aligned as type T" in the C++ standard library. I speak of something like:

```
template<class U,class T>
constexpr size_t size_of(const T& x)
{
  return (sizeof(x) + sizeof(U) - 1)/sizeof(U);
}
```

If I knew the name I would easily find it but searching for functionality is much harder that searching for name.

Comment: Is not `alignof` what you search? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof

Comment: @ForEveR No, alignof gives the alignment, not the size: size_of<size_t>('X')==8 bytes on 64 bit machine, but alignof('X')==1 byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any function that provides an "size of X with alignment adjusted to size of U".

Your calculation seems wrong tho, I would use:

```
return (sizeof(x) + sizeof(U) - 1) & ~(sizeof(U)-1);
```

This assumes the size of U is always a power of two. If it's not always a power of two, then you need:

```
return (sizeof(x) + sizeof(U) - 1) - sizeof(x) % sizeof(U);
```

or

```
return ((sizeof(x) + sizeof(U) - 1)/sizeof(U)) * sizeof(U);
```

(Your function calculates the size of `x` as units of `U`)

However, if you want to "fix" the alignment of a struct or class, you could use attributes - unfortunately, compilers have different ideas on how to solve this:

in gcc and clang:

```
struct T { ... } __attribute__((aligned(sizeof(U))));
```

in msvc and compatible:

```
__declspec( align( sizeof(U) ) )  struct T { ... }
```

(I'm not 100% sure that sizeof(U) actually works - you may need to code it as 2, 4, 8, 16 or whatever, and I believe both of these will require the alignment to always be a power of 2)

Comment: "Your function calculates the size of x as units of U": Yes it does. This is also usable because I will use the function to place POD:s so if the value was rescaled I would need to divide back to get units of U.